# Message app with node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat app with node.js and socket.io and need to save messages sent so anybody who did not see the chat can see it if they log on later. I only want the messages to be saved for 5 hours. Any Ideas

Comment: Save it to a database with a timestamp so you return only the messages that are less than 5 hours old

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is using [Redis](https://redis.io/). Here is a client for node from [GitHub](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis).

Comment: Redis would be problematic if the redis process ever has to shutdown or restart since it does not persist data to disk.  Even with just maintenance to upgrade, you'd lose the store.  I would think this application wants a more persistent data store.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes sure. Depends on applications. Anyway you can store data persistently, https://redis.io/topics/persistence